# Detect SignalR Hub Client Disconnect instantly

Tags: .net, signalr-hub, signalr.client

When is the SignalR Hub OnDisconnected raised on server side, for the the .net client that crash or close without calling the ***Stop*** method?

I am testing with the SignalR .NET client, not the javascript client.
If I call the ***Stop*** method on the client, the Hub will raise ***OnDisconnected*** method immediately.

But if I close the client or kill the process, the Hub will raise ***OnDisconnected*** method only after about 10 seconds.

How can I detect instantly that the client is disconnected?

Answer (score 5):

Having read the documentation for [SignalR events here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events), I spotted this section:

> When a connection is inactive, periodically the server sends a
>   keepalive packet to the client. As of the date this article is being
>   written, the default frequency is every 10 seconds

There is a section that describes how to change the keepalive setting e.g.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make long polling connections wait a maximum of 110 seconds for a
    // response. When that time expires, trigger a timeout command and
    // make the client reconnect.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);

    // Wait a maximum of 30 seconds after a transport connection is lost
    // before raising the Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

    // For transports other than long polling, send a keepalive packet every
    // 10 seconds. 
    // This value must be no more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value.
    GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}
```

Thus you could look into reducing that value, in order to be notified quicker of when a client connection ha gone down.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the info.  But from my testing, the KeepAlive only affects the Hub Client proxy time to raise the StateChanged event. I already try to set the ConnectionTimeout to 6 seconds and KeepAlive to 2 seconds on the server side, but it has no effect on the Hub OnDisconnected method.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I detect instantly that the client is disconnected?

You can't, due to the way TCP works, until you try to send data to that client. As @JasonEvans' answer explains, SignalR by default sends data (a "keepalive" message) every ten seconds.